# Azure Functions .NET 5 fails to start after changing value in local settings file

Tags: json.net, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

This is a very strange problem and want to see if anyone else can replicate the issue.

I start a brand new Azure Functions app targeting .NET 5. Mine is a timer function but I don't it matters what type of function it is.

I then add a value in my `local.settings.json` file:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "MY_CONNECTION_STRING_FOR_AZURE_STORAGE",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
        "MY_APP_ID": "1324"
      }
    }
}
```

I modify the `Program.cs` to read this value:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
   .ConfigureAppConfiguration(c =>
    {
            c.AddEnvironmentVariables();

             var config = c.Build();

             var id = config.GetValue<string>("MY_APP_ID");
     })
     .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();
```

I then run the app and it seems to start up fine.

Then, I modify the `local.settings.json` file and add a section -- see below:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "MY_CONNECTION_STRING_FOR_AZURE_STORAGE",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
        "MY_APP_ID": "1324",
        "MyApp": {
            "MY_APP_ID": "1324"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the app, I get the following error:
[image]

I then remove this section from my `local.settings.json` file and try running the app again and I get the same error.

It looks like, from this point on, there's nothing I can do to make this app run! If you noticed, I didn't change any code in my `Program.cs` file. Simply adding a section and removing it from `local.settings.json` file seems to render the app useless!

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: if you put a breakpoint at `var config = c.Build();` then is that being hit? just for validation, if you change the name of configuration setting `MY_APP_ID` to something else?

Comment: Just tested it again and got the same error after adding the `MyApp` section even though `var config = c.Build()` was hit. The only difference this time was that once I removed the `MyApp` section, the app actually ran again. In my previous attempts, removing the section would not fix the app and it would continue to throw the same error. Isnt this still pretty strange though that we can't have sections in `local.settings.json` file.

Comment: @user1672994 Have you tried this on your computer? I just want to see if others will have the same experience.

Comment: Not yet @sam. I will try in my free time and update you.